# chrome option --proxy-bypass-list=<-loopback> is not working

Tags: google-chrome, proxy

I setup a mock server on my local port 8500 for testing and behave like a proxy. I have read that chrome will ignore proxy settings for those request from localhost and need to add `--proxy-bypass-list=<-loopback>` to disable/bypass the rule. It was working until today.

My Configs:
System: MacOs Catalina, 10.15.3
Browser: Chrome Version 80.0.3987.149

the args to start chrome is `--ignore-certificate-errors,--proxy-bypass-list="<-loopback>",--proxy-server=http://localhost:8500`

I use selenium to do the automation and the base url is `http://localhost:8080`

After running, I can see the "external" urls calls like cdn js files, font files are actually going through the proxy server on port 8500. But I cannot find any localhost calls
Then I change the baseUrl to one of my testing environment which is not localhost, for example `10.10.10.10:8080` and I can see all traffic is going through proxy, including traffic to `10.10.10.10:8080`

I doubt the new chrome version breaks the bypassing rule since I had an update earlier today.

Please Help! Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

These lines worked for me :

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.addArguments("--proxy-bypass-list=<-loopback>");
WebDriver webDriver = new ChromeDriver(options);
```

Comment: thank you! I finally figured out that It may related to the quote around <-loopback>. I looked back this problem after a month I posted and I removed the quote, then it works. there's a chrome version upgrade during that month, so it could also new version fixed it

Comment: i had the same issue with the quotes, calling it like this comment fixed it for me .addArguments("--proxy-bypass-list=<-loopback>")